# Is there a method for comparing lists of DateTimeIndexes with different lengths to evaluate for common elements?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am still a beginner learning Python. I am trying to compare two lists of DateTimeIndexes to see if they contain at least 21 common dates/elements.

```
em_rotation_request_time_period = [pandas.date_range(start = '9/25/2025', end = '10/26/2025', freq = 'D')]

brooklyn_va_rotation_slots = 3

em_rotation_schedule = []
for start_dates, end_dates in zip (emergency_medicine_start_dates, emergency_medicine_end_dates):
    em_rotation_start_and_end_dates = [pandas.date_range (start = start_dates, end = end_dates, freq = 'D')]
    em_rotation_schedule.append (em_rotation_start_and_end_dates)

common = 0 
for dates in em_rotation_schedule:
    for dates_2 in em_rotation_request_time_period:
        if dates == dates_2:
            common += 1
        if common >= 21:
            brooklyn_va_rotation_slots = brooklyn_va_rotation_slots - 1

print ("Number of Rotation slots available at the Brooklyn VA:", brooklyn_va_rotation_slots
```

When I run my code I get this error message:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match
```

I have tried converting my lists to sets and tuples to work around the issue of comparing lists with unequal lengths. But, unfortunately I have had no success.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two lists of datetime data, you can run through one list and check if each element is in the other. I have attached a simple example that hopefully does what you're looking for:

```
from datetime import datetime

#Create example datetime date
dates = ['2023-04-10 07:00','2023-04-10 07:45','2023-04-10 09:00','2023-04-10 10:20','2023-04-10 12:00',
         '2023-04-10 12:50','2023-04-10 14:00','2023-04-10 15:10','2023-04-10 16:45','2023-04-10 18:00',
        '2023-04-11 07:20','2023-04-11 08:40','2023-04-11 10:00','2023-04-11 11:30']
a = [datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").date() for date in dates]

dates2 = ['2023-04-10 06:00','2023-04-10 07:45','2023-04-10 09:00','2023-04-10 10:55','2023-04-10 12:00',
         '2023-04-10 12:50','2023-04-10 12:50','2023-04-10 15:10','2023-04-10 16:45','2023-04-10 18:00',
        '2023-04-11 07:20','2023-04-12 08:40','2023-04-11 10:00','2023-04-11 15:30','2023-04-11 11:30','2023-04-11 18:30']
b = [datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").date() for date in dates2]

#Check if values in 'b' are present in 'a', and count list of cases where this is true
values_in_common = len([i for i in b if i in a])
print(values_in_common)
```

For example data, I just used a list of datetime strings that I had from an old cold and converted them into a list of datetime objects. Hopefully the code is clear and achieves what you want, if not let me know and I can append things as necessary!